# Pyspark: RDD with list of tokens to RDD with one token per row

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of lists with tokens such as:

```
mylist = [['hello'],
          ['cat'],
          ['dog'],
          ['hey'],
          ['dog'],
          ['I', 'need', 'coffee'],
          ['dance'],
          ['dream', 'job']]

myRDD = sc.parallelize(mylist)
```

I'm struggling to find the opperation that will result in an RDD where each row is one token. My desired output is:

```
[['hello'],
['cat'],
['dog'],
['hey'],
['dog'],
['I'], 
['need'], 
['coffee'],
['dance'],
['dream'], 
['job']]
```

What's the right syntax for this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just `flatMap`:

```
myRDD.flatMap(lambda xs: ([x] for x in xs))
```

Comment: Assume you meant `x` vs `[x]`or more simply `myRDD.flatMap(lambda xs: xs)`

Comment: `[x]` is actually right, question expects RDD of single-element lists..